# Can a LED light bulb trip a gfci breaker?

Tags: electrical, lighting, circuit-breaker, gfci, led

The ceiling fan in my bedroom has three lights, all three are LED bulbs, but I replaced one months ago. There are three other lights on the same circuit and a couple of outlets, few are ever used at the same time and all the other light bulbs are LED as well. One night with two different light on and a few other things, the breaker tripped, I was able to determine it was the bedroom ceiling fan that was tripping it. Worried a mouse had chewed or other damage was done I checked all the wiring in the attic and ran a borescope through the wall at the switch and everything looked fine. I was about to take the ceiling fan down but decided to check the bulbs, noticing the one different bulb, I removed it and tested with no problems, once I put it back in it tripped again. Is it really that simple that one LED bulb can trip a GFCI breaker?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the breaker in question please?

Comment: If you put in a different bulb (as opposed to what I think you tested which is "this bulb" vs. "no bulb") does it trip? When it trips, is it a GFCI trip or a full breaker (overload) trip?

Comment: It is almost always a better use of time to imagine that a tripping GFCI is caused by an actual ground fault somewhere.  Maybe the bulb is *physically* causing a ground fault? Or the socket is touching the chassis?   But ... if you can reliably put the one bulb in and out and cause a trip every time, and reliably put a different bulb in and not cause a trip .... that's very conclusive!   Are you sure your breaker is tripping with a Ground Fault?  Does it have indicator lights?  A bad bulb could certainly cause an overcurrent fault, and your breaker may be a combo AFCI and tripping that way?

Answer (score 0):

Low-quality LED bulbs can sometimes introduce electrical noise or fluctuations into the circuit. GFCI breaker is sensitive to fluctuations in current. Replace the LED bulb with a different one. It will be better if you use the same type and brand as the other two bulbs in the ceiling fan.

Comment: Can you substantiate that electrical noise can cause GFCI faults and that GFCIs are sensitive to "fluctuations" and what exactly that means?   There are lots of electrical devices that "fluctuate" wildly in normal operation and don't trip GFCI breakers.